# Java - Double Comparison

Tags: java, if-statement

How can I do something like:

```
int a=5;
if(4<=a<=6){

}
```

in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it two conditions:

```
int a=5;
if(4<=a && a<=6){

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the obvious solution stated by others (`if(4<=a && a<=6)`), you can use [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)'s [`IntRange`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html):

```
Range range = new IntRange(4,6)
if (range.containsInteger(5)) {..}
```

It looks like a bit of an overkill, but depending on the situation (if it isn't as trivial) it can be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(4 <= a && a <= 6) {
  // do something
}
```

Of course, you could always write a function like this in some `Util` class:

```
class Util {
    public static boolean inclusiveBetween(int num, int a, int b) {
        return num >= a && num <= b;
    }
}
```

and then you can do something like

```
if(Util.inclusiveBetween(someResourceIntensiveOpReturningInt(), 4, 6)) {
    // do things
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, I don't think. What's wrong with

```
int a = 5;
if(a >= 4 && a <= 6) {
}
```

? If you need to compare many different variables, put them in an array and sort the array, then compare the arrays.

Comment: Well not necessarily if a is a function - it means having to call the function twice (or assigning to temporary variable).

Comment: Is it a function? In that case, store the output of the function first. If it's many functions, store their results in the array, then clone the array and sort it and compare the two arrays.

Comment: Variables aren't exactly evil, so I don't see how that's wrong... it's probably the same in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. Its ugly, but can be very slightly faster.

```
int a = 5;
if(a - Integer.MIN_VALUE - 4 <= 2 - Integer.MIN_VALUE) {

}
```

This exploits the use of underflow to turn two comparisons into one.  This can save about 1-2 nano-seconds. However, in some usecases it can cost the same amount, so only try it if you are trying to micro-tune a loop.